# Google Calendar API: calendar.events.freebusy vs calendar.freebusy

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have seen the description provided for these scopes in the console, but they are not clear for me.

What is the difference between these two scopes?

[image: scopes description]

Comment: I am curious to know, do you have a screenshot on where you see those scopes? Mainly because I do have an insight on the difference or you might be misreading the way the call is being made.

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz Added an image.

Answer (score 0):

**OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs**

**Calendar API:**

It would be important to clarify that all necessary scopes for any Google application can be found here:

- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

There are 5 scopes over the official documentation that allows you acess Calendar and their properties, plus another 2 that are used for managing Calendar Resources from Google Admin for organizations. This means that both of those are old and deprecated scopes (Potentially  from V2 or were removed due to being no longer necessary and packed under any other ones from the documentation):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.event.freebusy
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.freebusy
```

If you try to run or access any of these scopes you would be prompted with an alert similar to this:

[image]

As one final thing that can easily help you with deatils on what scopes are needed to query `Freebusy` information, you can review the authorization scopes needed to run it here:

- https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/freebusy/query

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I only added ```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.freebusy``` scope and queried successfully using instructions from https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/freebusy/query

Comment: It seems that one is no longer needed or required, you would need the two from the screenshots. If you remove the "calendar.freebusy" it should still queried successfully.